# How to run a JavaScript function when the user is visiting an hash link (#something) using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, fragment-identifier, hashchange

I have a webb application at `http://example.com/app` and I would like to show a form if the user is visiting `http://example/app#add-item`.

Is there any way I can use a jQuery script to add this functionallity?

My current jQuery script already has a structure like this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#search').keyup(
            function() { ... }
        );
    }
)
```

How can I show a form using someting like this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#search').keyup(
            function() { ... }
        );

        $('#add-item').visit( // .visit probably doesn't exist
            function() { content.innerHTML = myForm; }
        );
    }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something I do:

```
    var hash = (window.location.hash).replace('#', '');
    if (hash.length == 0) {
        //no hash
    }
    else {
        //use `hash`
        //example:
        if(hash == 'add-item'){
             //do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 - Just a minor nitpick; I would do `if(hash) { // since empty string == falsy } ` to save valuable bytes.

Comment: @karim79, doesn't `hash.length` take the same amount of time? and it also accounts for if the url is: `example.com/#`

Comment: It's not about the performance but about the smaller footprint (but again, just a nitpick! :) Since you're replacing the hash character with nothing, the example URL in your comment should still yield a falsy result.

Comment: @karim -- pick away, just not my nose

Answer (score 2):

Might be able to use the `hashchange` event, as shown at http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#search').keyup(
            function() { ... }
        );

        $('#add-item').click(
            function() { $("#content").html(myForm); }
        );
    }
);
```

I assume you have a element with id "content" where you want to display the form.

Comment: But this is only working if the user is clicking on a `#add-item` link and not if the user is visiting that url, or am I wrong?

Comment: yea, If that is the case you need to check the hash, on onload event of the Page. Which is already answered.